# How to send data to all Epoll fds?

Tags: linux, epoll

I've been trying to make a server and a client for chat using epoll for a week. I struggle too much since I'm a newbie at this networking stuff. I ended up with this code. (note: I connect to my server with telnet for now): http://textuploader.com/5e0ts

How am I supposed to send data to all registered fds in the epoll instance? I am trying to do this inside a loop in main loop but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, please include minimal code example demonstrating your problem directly into the question. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am new to this, and I do not know which part of the code causes the problem. I  can't minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that all of those registered FDs are waiting `EPOLLIN` event. If so when you send data to FDs in a loop, the specific FD can be "waked up", and receive data.

You should use `nonblocking IO`, because what you want to do is broadcasting, but `epoll_wait` function is a blocking function, and `epoll` model can only process the event one by one, unless you use a thread pool.

Actually, you can also finish this task using `EPOLLOUT` event to send data to FDs one by one with the help of `epoll`, instead of inside a loop in `epoll` loop.